# why do I always get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException using foreach

Tags: foreach, java-stream, indexoutofboundsexception

I change my older codes to newer by using stream.
But when I start tomcat it keep getting

> ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file xxx(my FilePath)  nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25091"

Can anyone tell me what causes this error? I really appreciate for your help.

```
/*old*/
for(String key:paramMap.keySet()){
    if(key.startsWith("NUMBER_OF_") ){
        String value = request.getParameter(key);
        if(value!=null && !value.equals("")){
            br.append(key.replace("NUMBER_OF_", "")).append(" = ")
                .append('"').append(value).append('"').append(" and ");
        }
    }
}

/*new*/
new ArrayList<>(paramMap.keySet()).stream().filter(p -> p.startsWith("NUMBER_OF_")).forEach(
    o ->{
        String value = request.getParameter(o);
        if(value!=null && !value.equals("")){
            br.append(o.replace("NUMBER_OF_", "")).append(" = ")
                .append('"').append(value).append('"').append(" and ");
        }
    });
```

The entire stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.61\webapps\web\WEB-INF\classes\com\ais\brm\web\controllers\system\metadic\MetaDicManageController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:260)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You would normally do `paramMap.keySet().stream().filter(` etc

Comment: the error still exists: nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: are you **sure** that happens on that particular piece of code?

Comment: @RickGeng posting the entire stack trace would help

Comment: @Eugene I have added it

Comment: @RickGeng what Spring version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/27/spring-framework-4-0-3-released-with-java-8-support-now-production-read), you need Spring version to be **at least** `4.0.3` to support java 8 features.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3 (in this case spring-asm) does not support Java8 features. 
You should return your code to Java7 ("old" variant) or upgrade Spring up to 4.0.3 as mentioned by Eugene above.